# Oracle - Can't Find Long Running Queries

Tags: oracle

What am I missing here? I am trying to test identifying long running queries.

I have a test table with about 400 million rows called mytest.
I ran `select * from mytest` in sqlplus

In another window, I ran the script below to see my long running query

```
select s.username, s.sid, s.serial#, s.schemaname, 
    s.program, s.osuser, s.status, s.last_call_et
    from v$session s
where last_call_et >= 1 – this is just for testing
```

My long running query does not show up in the result from the query above. If I change the criteria to be >=0, then I see my query showing the status as INACTIVE and last_call_et of 0 despite the fact that the query is still running. What can I do to see my long running queries like the `select * from...` above so that I can kill it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to understand what a query like `select * from mytest` is really doing under the covers because that's generally not going to be a long-running query.  Oracle doesn't ever need to materialize that result set and isn't going to read all the data as the result of a single call.  Instead, what goes on is a series of calls each of which cause Oracle to do a little bit of work.  The conversation goes something like this.

- Client: Hey Oracle, run the query for me: `select * from mytest`
- Oracle: Sure thing (`last_call_et` resets to 0 to reflect that a new call started).  I've generated a query plan and opened a cursor,
  here's a handle (note that no work has been done yet to actually
  execute the query)
- Client: Cool, thanks.  Using this cursor handle,
  fetch me the next 50 rows (the fetch size is a client-side setting)
- Oracle: Will do (`last_call_et` resets to 0 to reflect that a new call started).  I started full scanning the table, read a couple of
  blocks, and got 50 rows.  Here you go.
- Client: OK, I've processed
  those.  Using this cursor handle, fetch the next 50 rows
- Repeat until all the data is fetched

At no point in this process is Oracle ever really being asked to do more than read a handful of blocks to get the 50 rows (or whatever the fetch size the client is requesting).  At any point, the client could simply not request the next batch of data so Oracle doesn't need to do anything long-running.  Oracle doesn't track the application think time between requests for more data-- it has no idea whether the client is a GUI that is in a tight loop fetching data or whether it is displaying a result to a human and waiting for a human to hit the "next" button.  The vast majority of the time, the session is going to be `INACTIVE` because it's mostly waiting for the client to request the next batch of data (which it generally won't do until it had formatted the last batch of data for display and done the work to display it).

When most people talk about a long-running query, they're talking about a query that Oracle is actively processing for a relatively long time with no waits on a client to fetch the data.

Comment: Coool Explanation Justin!!

Comment: Hi Justin, Once again, thanks aginfor your response and explanation of how Oracle handles a select * from query. One question I have is why v$session shows last_call_et as zero?

Comment: @user3524242 - Because each time the client calls the database and asks it to do work, the `last_call_et` is reset because those are each separate calls to the database.  I updated my answer to make that more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the below script to find long running query:**

```
select * from
(
  select
     opname,
     start_time,
     target,
     sofar,
     totalwork,
     units,
     elapsed_seconds,
     message
   from
        v$session_longops
  order by start_time desc
)
where rownum <=1;
```